# Vortices and Branch Cuts

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $\sigma =e^{i\theta}$ on the unit circle (where we restrict $|\theta| <\pi$ and consider a cycle of $\sigma_1 \to \sigma_2 \to \cdots \to \sigma_N \to \sigma_1$. For each directed edge, we can define $\nabla_{1\to 2} \theta = \theta_2 -\theta_1$ and then define $\delta_{1\to 2} \theta$ to be that of $\nabla_{1\to 2} \theta$ within the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ so that $\nabla_{1\to 2} \theta = \delta_{1\to 2} \theta -2\pi m_{1\to 2}$ where $m_{1\to 2} \in \{0,\pm 1\}$. What are the possible values of
$$
\oint m \equiv \sum_{i=1}^N m_{i\to i+1}
$$
By construction, neighboring $m$s cannot sum to $\pm 2$ and everytime we close the cycle, it seems that we need to subtract $-1$ if the summation of $m$s before closing the cycle is $ >0$, so my guess would be that the values can be anything between $-\lfloor N/2\rfloor+1,...,\lfloor N/2\rfloor-1$.
For example, if $N=4$, it's only possible for $\oint m \in \{\pm 1,0\}$ (proven by construction). This seems related to the branch cut of the complex logarithm, but I'm not quite sure how to prove this exactly.